# Compare strings from objects based on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React/Redux application and I got the following problem:

I got a reducer like this:

```js
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case action.type === FILTER.LIST_TYPES:
      return Object.keys(state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is the action types object:

```js
export const FILTER = {
  LIST_TYPES: "FILTER/LIST_TYPES"
};


export const listFilterTypes = () => ({
  type: FILTER.LIST_TYPES
});
```

Now, when I `dispatch` this code, I receive `false` on the equality check like this *(because they are both a string, but not the same type)*:

```
console.log(action.type === FILTER.LIST_TYPES);
```

I could change this for example to `==`, but ESLINT does not like that and it can have some funky behaviour.. Is there a better approach to compare these object strings?

**EDIT:**
They are both the same value when I `console.log` them:

```
action.type: "FILTER/LIST_TYPES"
FILTER.LIST_TYPES: "FILTER/LIST_TYPES"
```

Comment: `case action.type === FILTER.LIST_TYPES` should be `case FILTER.LIST_TYPES` in your switch statement.

Comment: @DennisMartinez That worked like a charm and looks much cleaner too! Thank you so much!

Comment: yes,  you were basically switch casing between string and boolean. won't go through that case .

Comment: `return Object.keys(state);` seems very strange to me. This will replace the entire state with just a list of keys. Any code that expects the original shape of state will fail miserably.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Didn't think of that, thanks

Comment: @Thimma In my projects where I use Redux, `state` is an object. In my reducers, I copy that object, update it, then return it. This maintains the shape so that expected keys will either be there or signal that the app needs to fill it in somehow (such as with an API request). Changing the shape drastically is prone to break things.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah me too, I just messed the code up because I wanted an array of object keys as a return value, but it doesn't work that way lol

Comment: @Thimma Depending on what you are doing with those keys, maybe a reducer isn't the right solution. You can easily get the list of keys in `mapStateToProps()` for a component, for example. Or in the component itself.